# asp.net website user load matrix

Tags: iis

I wanted to know and calculate my existing asp.net website infrastructure can manage how many no of user load at a time

Answer (score 0):

The only way to answer this question is to perform load tests. [Apache Bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) is a good tool for this. [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) is another one that provides a GUI.